# group rows in plain sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

I have a Table with columns Date and Number, like so:

```
date        Number 
1-1-2012    1
1-2-2012    1
1-3-2012    2
1-4-2012    1
```

I want to make a sql query that groups the rows with the same Number and take the minimum date. The grouping only may occur when the value iof Number is the same as previous / next row. So the rsult is

```
date        Number 
1-1-2012    1
1-3-2012    2
1-4-2012    1
```

Comment: Hi Joe, the order of records is by date. How can I use previous / next grouping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
WITH   CTE AS(
       SELECT * ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DATE] ) - 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NUMBER ORDER BY [DATE] ) AS ROW_NUM
       FROM TABLE1)
SELECT NUMBER,MIN(DATE) AS DATE
FROM   CTE
GROUP BY ROW_NUM,NUMBER
ORDER BY DATE
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c36c/11)

Comment: +1 I was trying to do the same but you beat me. [See SqlFeddle of your query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c36c/11)

Comment: @hims056: Thanks a lot.. I was trying to create a fiddle .. but it was throwing error for me .. I thought ROW_NUMBER() function doent work in fiddle

Comment: SQLFiddle is very useful tool. And it support `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: Works like a charm :) I didnt know about PARTITION BY and OVER syntax. thnx for sharing and learn me something new

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Number, MIN(date)
FROM table
GROUP BY Number
ORDER BY Number
```

since you requirement is a bit more specific, how about this? I have not checked it myself, but something that might work, considering you requirement..

```
SELECT date, Number FROM (
SELECT Number, 
(SELECT MIN(date) FROM #table t2 WHERE t1.date <> t2.date AND t1.Number = t2.Number) AS date 
FROM table t1
) AS a
GROUP BY number, date
```

Comment: Don't be too quick to point out simple questions; your answer doesn't achieve what the user wants.

Comment: There.. updated my comment for you :) And on another note since I am being stupid, why does my solution not work? Time to learn something, in my case.

Comment: I also updated my comment :) Your solution doesnt work because the query will give back 2 rows and I want 3 rows!

Comment: Joe's answer is the right one, I treid yours as well, but it got the date's all mixed up. Thank you for responding!!